# java io - regular expressions not working - Why

Tags: java, regex, java-io

I wrote a program to print the files having extension of doc or pdf. But it not working. Same regular expression is working with direct filenames instead of filenames retrieving from file system, it working.
what's wrong:

```
import static java.nio.file.FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.FileSystems;
import java.nio.file.FileVisitResult;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.PathMatcher;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.SimpleFileVisitor;
import java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes;

public class FindDuplicateFiles {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String startingDirStr ="/Users/ravi/documents/LATEST SOURCE";//"."; 
        String pattern ="([^\\s]+(\\.(?i)(doc|docx|pdf))$)";//"*.doc*";//"((\\.(?i)(pdf|doc))$)";//"^(?:.*\\.(?:docx|pdf)$";// ".*\\.(?:doc|pdf)$";//

        Path startingDir = Paths.get(startingDirStr);

        Finder finder = new Finder(pattern);
        Files.walkFileTree(startingDir, finder);
        finder.done();
    }

    public static class Finder extends SimpleFileVisitor<Path> {

        private final PathMatcher matcher;
        private int numMatches = 0;

        Finder(String pattern) {
            matcher = FileSystems.getDefault().getPathMatcher("glob:" + pattern);
        }

        // Compares the glob pattern against
        // the file or directory name.
        void find(Path file) {
            Path name = file.getFileName();
            if (name != null && matcher.matches(name)) {
                numMatches++;

                System.out.println(name);
                //System.out.println(file);
            }
        }

        // Prints the total number of
        // matches to standard out.
        void done() {
            System.out.println("Matched: " + numMatches);
        }

        // Invoke the pattern matching
        // method on each file.
        @Override
        public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) {
            find(file);
            return CONTINUE;
        }

        // Invoke the pattern matching
        // method on each directory.
        @Override
        public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir, BasicFileAttributes attrs) {
            find(dir);
            return CONTINUE;
        }

        @Override
        public FileVisitResult visitFileFailed(Path file, IOException exc) {
            System.err.println(exc);
            return CONTINUE;
        }
    }

}
```

But It working fine:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class FindDocuments {

    private Pattern pattern;
    private Matcher matcher;

    private static final String IMAGE_PATTERN = "([^\\s]+(\\.(?i)(doc|docx|pdf))$)";

    public FindDocuments() {
        pattern = Pattern.compile(IMAGE_PATTERN);
    }

    public boolean validate(final String image) {

        matcher = pattern.matcher(image);
        return matcher.matches();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FindDocuments fd = new FindDocuments();
        String[] aaa = new String[] { "a.doc", "a.docx", "a.pdf", "a.PDF", "..DOC", "..PDF" };
        for (String temp : aaa) {
            boolean valid = fd.validate(temp);
            System.out.println("Image is valid : " + temp + " , " + valid);

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tell [`FileSystem.getPathMatcher(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystem.html#getPathMatcher-java.lang.String-) to interpret the pattern as a "glob" instead of "regex".